# Did juvenile clones execute Order 66?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, order-66

At the end of the Clone Wars, there are still countless clones, already out of the incubation vats but not yet of age to be deployed into active service. All of them already have inhibitor chips implanted to ensure compliance to Order 66.

When Order 66 came down, did these juvenile clones of all ages join the adult clone troopers present in hunting down and exterminating all present Jedi across the Kaminoan cloning facilities?

Answers with content from either canonicities are welcome.

Comment: For anyone wondering, this question was inspired by a YouTube comment suggesting how kid clones might have attacked Jedi with canteen food and various cutlery...

Comment: I don't think there's any good evidence that any Jedi were stationed on Kamino...

Comment: Well at the least, they should be actively hunting known Jedi traitors in the vicinity

Comment: We're there any in the vicinity? I'm not caught up on "Clone Wars" but I don't recall that the Jedi did more than visit...

Comment: @Valorum Shaak Ti seems to have been permently stationed there in one of the TCW arcs; of course she was on Coruscant for Order 66, but it doesn't seem impossible that someone had taken her place

Comment: @JasonBaker - We know that there were adult troops on Kamino to defend the facility. Presumably Sidious contacted those forces rather than issuing a general order to the whole city.

Comment: @Valorum but imagine the headline: "Traitor Jedi Attacks, Murders Children".

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Wait, are we talking about Vader? Or...

Comment: @TylerH No, I just meant if Palpatine got clonelings to attack Jedi, he could spin the story to make the Jedi look bad (assuming they fought back). I assume he didn't let any reporters into the Jedi Temple.

Comment: As an aside, does anyone else feel like this has the potential to be a really good story? Basically a group of young clones  are forced to out smart and kill a jedi that they believe to be a traitor after the jedi takes out the adult clones. Very much a tragic hero sort of story.

Comment: @Alarion Imperial Commandos: Teen Angst

Answer (score 3):

Sadly no canon info directly available to my knowledge. So lets take a look at the clones themselves. They are since "childhood" trained for war. Additionally all of them have been implanted with the chip since their "creation".

So it is highly probable that even adolescent clones attacked all Jedi they could see (IF they got word of order 66 being activated and thus the chip doing its work).  And I don't think they used the canteen food....more the forks and knives and all tricks they already got trained at martial arts wise....and naturally all blasters they could get from the dead adult clones the jedi had murdered already.

Answer (score -3):

Well, I believe all clones executed order 66 because it was emperor Palpatine (he knew about the clones) telling them to execute order 66 and it seemed they all turned on their masters, soooooo... I would say every clone participated in order 66.

Comment: Hello Plush Sith, and welcome to the SF & Fantasy Stack. While we appreciate your answer, we prefer answer that are backed by sources, instead of being just an opinion. Can you dig up any references? Oh, by the way, have you taken the [tour] yet?